# How to match the regex when a figure contains ,

Tags: regex

There are figures  example
1,456,876,678

I am using regex as below

```
\d{1,3}(?:[,](\d{3}))

It match 1. 1,456
         2. 876,678
```

But if I use

```
\d{1,3}(?:[,](\d{3}))*. Result is 1,456,876,678 //which is fine
```

Now If the value/figure is "0". By using

```
\d{1,3}(?:[,](\d{3}))*
```

It also matches 0 which I do not want. I don't want to match the value which is equal to 0

Comment: What are your MIN and MAX acceptable values? 1 for MIN, what about MAX?

Comment: \d{1,3}(?:[,](\d{3}))+ also works now

Answer (score 0):

For that you can slightly modify your `regex` to:

`[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:[.](\d{3}))*`

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/eT9kH3)</kbd>

Comment: @user3138879, Answer updated. I had missed something... Sorry